# ¿Cómo recupero GRUB para iniciar ubuntu despues de formatear y reinstalar Yosemite de una partición?

Tags: ubuntu, macos

Tengo cuatro particiones en mi ordenador, sda1( que contiene UEFI el bootloader de Mac), sda2( partición con Mac OSx Yosemite), sda3( partición dedicada a GRUB, bootloader de linux) y sda4( partición donde tengo Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

Formatie la partición donde tenía instalado Yosemite y volvi a instalarlo. Luego de reinstalar, Yosemite bootea perfecto, pero al acceder al menú para seleccionar el bootloader UEFI o GRUB(precionando 'alt' al iniciar el ordenador) me encontré con la sorpresa que la partición donde tengo instalado GRUB no funciona, por lo que no puedo bootear Ubuntu.
¿Cómo hago para recuperar la partición que contiene GRUB?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que este sitio no es el correcto para postear tu pregunta, pero intenta lo siguiente:

-Consigue un Live CD de Ubuntu, insértalo y reinicia, ya iniciado vas a ejecutar:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Te aparecerá esta ventana y elegirás el botón "*Recommended repair*"

[image: Boot reapir]

También puedes ver las opciones avanzadas si quieres personalizar mas cosas de GRUB, todo es de manera gráfica.

[image: Opciones avanzadas]

***Si quieres hacerlo mediante Terminal y aprender más, te recomiendo que visites el [artículo original](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)***

Comment: Muchas gracias x4amp73r!